# Why do uploaded files gets saved with an all-caps file extension?

Tags: 7

On my product site any uploaded images get saved with the .JPG saved in all-caps. I don't see the same issue on my local development machine so I would think it has to be a server issue? The live site uses NGINX.

Comment: Perhaps this is a dumb question, but do the original files have an uppercase extension? Also, do you have any modules installed performing file renaming such as Transliteration?

Comment: no to both questions

Comment: @MotoTribe As the question seems interesting please post your answer if you find. +1

Comment: it appears as if they are uploaded in all caps filenames. Maybe most cameras store filenames all caps. My Sony and my gopro camera for example do. I wonder if there is a way to force the filenames to lowercase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely not a server (nginx) issue, as the server does not do anything with the files (well, it transfers them bit by bit). Like Charlie already asked, do you use any modules?

**Edit:** To answer your second question, of course you can “force” lowercase extensions. But personally I wouldn’t bug your users with that, they should simply upload whatever they have. Instead simply alter the files extension before saving the file to disk/database.

[hook_file_presave()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_file_presave/7) seems like the correct way to do this. You would have to create a little module and have a look at the file variable that’s passed to your hook, then simply `strtolower()` the file extension.

Comment: good to know that it can't be the server. I use a bunch of modules of course, none that would have any effect on an uploaded file name.

Answer (score 0):

Files on the camera are stored using a very simple file system using 8.3 file names, which by default are upper-case (originally these file systems didn't distinguish between upper and lower case in filenames)